# Independence of two distinct functions of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Given two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, let $$ \begin{aligned} Z_1 &:= X + a f(Y) \\ Z_2 &:= X + b f(Y) \end{aligned} $$ where $f$ is an unspecified but well-behaved (i.e., continuously differentiable, etc) function, and $a, b \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ are arbitrary constants.  Assuming $a \neq b$, under what conditions will $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be independent?

My intuition is that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ will be independent when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but I just don't know how to generally proceed to get to a solution to my question. And if my conjecture is true, is this an “if and only if” claim? Or are there examples where dependence of $X$ and $Y$ still allow for independent $Z_1$ and $Z_2$?

Comment: "My intuition is that $Z_1$  $Z_2$ will generally be independent" Why? On the contrary, in general they will  NOT be independent

Comment: My intuition is based on implicitly assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But I wanted to leave out such an assumption. Any suggestions for finding conditions for independence would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, the function $f$ complicates things with no purpose. Just define $Z=f(Y)$ and forget about $f$

Comment: What do you mean "forget about $f$"? That is part of my question.

Comment: @leonbloy means that since $Y$ appears in the definitions of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ only as an argument to $f(\cdot)$, you don't need $Y$ itself; you can just assign $W := f(Y)$, and then $Z_1 := X+aW$ and $Z_2 := X+bW$. After all, a random variable, strictly speaking, is a function on a measurable space, so $W$ ends up just being a composed function.

Comment: @BrianTung My thinking was that the general independence conditions I seek should involve $Y$. How could they not since $X$ and $Y$ are the given random variables? The question reposed as you have written suggests I would only need conditions on $a$ and $b$. Is that correct, and if so, how do I go about finding these conditions?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't depend on $Y$; it's that because the dependence is *only* ever through the function $f$, you might as well subsume that and just define $W := f(Y)$. ¶ By way of analogy, suppose you know that you have one oil's viscosity is a function of humidity and applied voltage to a heating plate, and another oil's viscosity is another function of humidity and applied voltage. But wait: Both voltages impact the situation only through the temperature they induce in the oil, which is a direct function of that voltage. So just express viscosity in terms of humidity and temperature.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't change anything; it's just a way of simplifying thinking about the problem, by eliminating extraneous complications.